# Not getting the home page

Tags: html, spring-boot

Im not getting my home page, getting the below error while running my application:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Nov 12 13:37:08 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.IRonak</groupId>
    <artifactId>MoneyManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MoneyManager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**MoneyManagerApplication.java**

```
package com.IRonak.MoneyManager;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan({"com.IRonak.MoneyManager.Controller"})
public class MoneyManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MoneyManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**MoneyManagerController**

```
package com.IRonak.MoneyManager.Controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MoneyManagerController {


 @RequestMapping("/")
public String home(){


     return "home";
 }


}
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Money Manager</h1>
<p>Manges your Expenses</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your home.html is under src/main/resources/static

Then do this:

```
@Controller
public class MoneyManagerController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: can some one tell me why i have to keep it under static ,why not under templates. And my other  projects worked without ".html " extension like 'return "home" '.

Comment: by default they have to be there but if you want to have them somewhere else then you have to write a configuration class to specify that

Comment: If the answer works, may you also accept it for  others who come here in the future to show that this solved your issue